# yarn start in React Native doesn't work after upgrading from 0.62.2 to 0.68. Fails silently

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I just upgraded from RN 0.62.2 to 0.68 using the `react-native upgrade` command and using the upgrade helper to fix the unchanged files. Now when I run `yarn start --reset-cache`, it just runs `react-native start --reset-cache` and then prints `Done in 1.20s.`. I am not able to understand what do I do or what did I do.

I am not sure what all information I should post here. Do let me know. Any help here is supremely appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried just `yarn`?

Comment: So my question here is that the metro bundler isn't running when I do `yarn start`. Just `yarn` does dependency installation.

Answer (score 0):

first what the error you get?

second the best way to update is to use read:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading

and use this:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

please be careful when upgrading react-native,
many libraries from the yarn/npm maybe should be updated to.

when you update react-native you have to be ready to get errors.

wish you luck!

Comment: The error is that `yarn start` is supposed to run the metro bundler but it just silently exits without any errors.
```
 yarn start                            
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-native start
✨  Done in 2.46s.
```
This is what happens.

Comment: Also when I did the upgrade, the first thing that happened is, it skipped a bunch of files because they were in the template but not in the project. Next it skipped another bunch of files because they were modified from the previous version. So I used the upgrade helper page to manually copy paste the new stuff and update my project.